# Returning array from PHP function only gives first element

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to dynamically populate admin page of my site with sections from the database.

The problem is that I want to get all sections added in the database, and to be easier to me, I use a function.

This code prints me out the first array element.

`functions.php`

```
<?php
function fetchAdminSections ($user_id){
    global $pdo;

    $get_sections = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id`, `section_name`, `section_description` FROM `administration_sections` WHERE `admin_added_this` = :admin");
    $get_sections->execute([
        ':admin' => $user_id
    ]);

    while ($row = $get_sections->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $sections = [];

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['section_name'];
        $description = $row['section_description'];
        $sections[$id]['section_name'] = $name;
        $sections[$id]['section_description'] = $description;
        return $sections;
    }
}
?>
```

`index.php`

```
 <?php
    include 'functions.php';

    $elements = fetchAdminSections($user_id);
    print_r($elements);
 ?>
```

---

What I get is:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [section_name] => test1 [section_description] => test ) )
```

Simply returning `$row` inside `while` gives me a similar thing:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [section_name] => test1 [section_description] => test )
```

---

I'd like to get all sections, and loop through them!

Comment: move `return $sections;` after loop

Comment: Every time you loop you initiate variable `$sections` again which means it is constantly overwritten. Move this line `$sections = [];` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your array outside the loop and return AFTER the loop is finished...

```
<?php
function fetchAdminSections ($user_id){
    global $pdo;

    $get_sections = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id`, `section_name`, `section_description` FROM `administration_sections` WHERE `admin_added_this` = :admin");
    $get_sections->execute([
        ':admin' => $user_id
    ]);

    $sections = [];
    while ($row = $get_sections->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['section_name'];
        $description = $row['section_description'];
        $sections[$id]['section_name'] = $name;
        $sections[$id]['section_description'] = $description;
    }

    return $sections;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your return statement outside of your while loop.

The way its done now, it returns from the while loop in the first run. A function cant return a value multiple times. Edit it something like this:

```
$sections = [];
while ($row = $get_sections->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['section_name'];
    $description = $row['section_description'];
    $sections[$id]['section_name'] = $name;
    $sections[$id]['section_description'] = $description;

}
return $sections;
```